# search & replace: how to add a line feed to break up a line?

Tags: regular-expression, replace

So, I have the following line where I would like to find all the {#}= and put them on a new line.  Of course there can be more then 9 value entries and there is more text on the line, so I am thinking of looking for something like comma, space, one or more digits, and finally the equal sign, then add a line feed between the comma and the space.

The question is: how do I do that in vi across multiple lines?

```
  sion] ],{1=ValueEntry, 2=ValueEntry, 3=ValueEntry, 4=ValueEntry, 5=ValueEntry, 6=ValueEntry, 7=ValueEntry, 8=ValueEntry}]

  sion] ],{1=ValueEntry, 
  2=ValueEntry, 
  3=ValueEntry, 
  4=ValueEntry, 
  5=ValueEntry, 
  6=ValueEntry, 
  7=ValueEntry, 
  8=ValueEntry}]
```

Comment: `\r` adds a new line in a replacement. `%s/\v(,\s)(\d\=)/\1\r\2/g` will add the new line after the comma and the space

Comment: I think @Steve solution is the way to go, but if your filetype is supported by the plugin https://github.com/AndrewRadev/splitjoin.vim could be useful too

Answer (score 5):

You can add a line break by using the atom `\r` in the replacement part of the `:s` command (while in the pattern part, you would need to use `\n` to **match** a line break).

That allows to split your string using the following command:

```
:s/,\ze \d\+=/&\r/g
```

That is search for a comma (and end the match there), followed by a space, at least one number and a `=` and replace the comma in this case with itself (using the special atom `&` which corresponds to the complete match) followed by a line break (`\r`).